# How can I put a Liquid tag highlight in an ordered list?

Tags: markdown, highlight, jekyll, liquid

This is what I **want** the page to be:

```
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second
    <code></code>
  </li>
  <li>third</li>
</ol>
```

This is what I'm writing:

```
1. first
2. second
  {% highlight ruby %}
  code here
  {% endhighlight %}
3. third
```

And this is how it renders:

```
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
</ol>
<div class="highlight>
  code here
</div>
<ol>
  <li>third</li>
</ol>
```

So how do I write and it will render as what I want it to be?

Comment: So far, you can't: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/588

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to figure out how to use the "Pygments" highlighting for code blocks inside of lists. It is possible to do a basic code block without highlighting with the following:

```
1. first
2. second

        code here

3. third
```

The white space placement here is important. The way that snippet of code works, there is a a blank line between `2. second` and the `code here` line. Additionally, there are two tabs before the `code here` text (Eight spaces should also work).

The output from the above using jekyll 1.0.3 with `markdown: kramdown` set in the _config.yml file produces:

```
<ol>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>
    <p>second</p>

    <pre><code> code here
</code></pre>
  </li>
  <li>third</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way:

```
1. first
2. second
 : {% highlight ruby %}
code
code
code
{% endhighlight %}
3. third
```

This renders as a definition list though (`<dt>` and `<dd>` tags) which is probably technically incorrect use of that markup so if you're super strict about that kind of thing you might not like it, but I haven't been able to find another way without writing your own plugin to generate lists which will completely change the way you write them.