# markdown display incorrect when add code block in list

Tags: css, markdown, jekyll, pygments, kramdown

I am using pygments and kramdown in my [jekyll blog](https://github.com/liuzxc/liuzxc.github.io).

I tried to add code block to markdown list, but display incorrect.

```
1. first

2. second

    {% highlight ruby %}
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
    {% endhighlight %}

3. third
```

[image: 2015-10-29 6 39 28]

generated html:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>first</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>second</p>
  </li>
</ol>

<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-ruby" data-lang="ruby"><span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">foo</span>
  <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s1">&#39;foo&#39;</span>
<span class="k">end</span></code></pre></div>

<ol>
  <li>third</li>
</ol>
```

but if I write like this, it is no problem.

````
1. first

2. second

    ```
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
    ```

3. third
````

[image: 2015-10-29 6 41 37]

Is this pygments or kramdown problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I put a Liquid tag highlight in an ordered list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995467/how-can-i-put-a-liquid-tag-highlight-in-an-ordered-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with Liquid or kramdown individually, but how they operate together. Jekyll seems to be processing the files with Liquid first, followed by passing the result to kramdown to be parsed as markdown.

This means that kramdown is seeing something like this:

```
1. first

2. second


<figure class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-ruby" data-lang="ruby">    <span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">foo</span>
      <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s1">'foo'</span>
    <span class="k">end</span>
    </code></pre></figure>


3. third
```

Liquid isn’t keeping the indentation of the code section, and so when processed as markdown it is causing the list to close and the third item to be seen as a new list.

In order to use the `highlight` Liquid tag here you need to ensure the result of Liquid processing is the appropriately indented markdown. I don’t know if this is possible with plain Jekyll, but you could do this fairly simply with a plugin (so this won’t work if you are using Github pages).

Create a file named something like `_plugins/indent_filter.rb` with these contents:

```ruby
module IndentFilter
  def indent(input)
    input.gsub(/\n/, "\n    ")
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(IndentFilter)
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
1. first

2. second

{% capture the_code %}
{% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
{% endcapture %}
{{ the_code | indent }}

3. third
```

Note that you need to use `capture` first in order to use the `indent` filter (you could probably create a custom tag to use instead of `highlight` if you prefer). Also note that the Liquid tags aren’t indented at all, that is handled by the filter.

The result of this after Liquid processing but before markdown is something like this:

```
1. first

2. second

    <figure class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-ruby" data-lang="ruby"><span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">foo</span>
      <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s1">'foo'</span>
    <span class="k">end</span></code></pre></figure>

3. third
```

Now the code block is correctly indented so that markdown sees it as the content of the second list item. Since it is already HTML kramdown doesn’t try to process it further, but also it doesn’t cause the list to be closed. The result after markdown processing is:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <p>first</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>second</p>

    <figure class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-ruby" data-lang="ruby"><span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">foo</span>
   <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s1">'foo'</span>
 <span class="k">end</span></code></pre></figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>third</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Would `replace` work instead of a custom filter?

`{{ the_code | replace: '\n', '\n    ' }}`

Comment: @ErikGillespie it looks like it should, but doesn’t seem to when I test it. I wonder if Liquid isn’t parsing `\n` as a newline (I tried double quotes too). It would be a better solution if that would work, since it would avoid custom plugin code.

Comment: Seems it not working for nested list. I have changed rb file with double tab space like this `input.gsub(/\n/, "\n     ")` . But it collapse my Html page.

@matt suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Jekyll `highlight` tag is trimming the content. Since the spaces before your `end` statement are in the middle of the text, it won't get trimmed.

Unindent the whole block of code and it should render correctly.

```
1. first

2. second

    {% highlight ruby %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
    {% endhighlight %}

3. third
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code is showing correct, but the order still wrong.

Comment: You need 2 levels of indent. One to make it a child of of the list item and one to make it a code block.

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified the @matt answer.

We can able to use the \t in the rb file instead of 4 space.

Due to this changes we can able to use the indent for 1st level and 2nd second level list items too.

Find the rb file below

```
module IndentFilter
  def indent1(input)
    input.gsub(/\n/, "\n\t")
  end
  def indent2(input)
    input.gsub(/\n/, "\n\t\t")
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(IndentFilter)
```