# kramdown turns tabs into spaces in indeted codeblocks

Tags: markdown, jekyll, indentation, kramdown

I'm using jekyll which in turn uses kramdown to convert markdown into html and I can't get the following example to render correctly: I used `\t` to show a tab, `\s` to show a space

````
*\tHere is some code in a list:

\t```python
\tdef bar():
\t\treturn 4;
```
````

and it should render like

- Here is some code in a list:

  ```py
  def bar():
  \treturn 4;
  ```

however i end up with

- Here is some code in a list:

  ```py
  def bar():
  \s\s\s\sreturn 4;
  ```

The issue here for me is that I'd like to use the css attribute `tab-size` to configure the width of the tabs but this obviously doesn't work for spaces.

I'm assuming this is to do with kramdown's assumption that tabs are 4 spaces wide?

I've also tried to indent the heading of the list with various amounts of tabs as [Embed a code block in a list item with proper indentation in kramdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987908/embed-a-code-block-in-a-list-item-with-proper-indentation-in-kramdown) suggests, but without any luck.

Is there some option to forbid kramdown replacing tabs with spaces? Or some other way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: [The docs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#usage-of-tabs) only say "1 tab is 4 spaces", but I wonder if you could get what you want by switching to the GFM (GitHub flavoured Markdown) parser? This is set in `_config.yml`, in `kramdown.input` (set to `GFM`).

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but one that produces the desired output:

By indenting using spaces the tabs are preserved as I want.

so

````
*\sHere is some code in a list:

\s\s```python
\s\sdef bar():
\s\s\treturn 4;
\s\s```
````

produces the desired output for some reason. This might however not be stable, as https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#usage-of-tabs explicitly states that "the results [of tabs after spaces] may be unexpected".

@Benjamin w. `GFM` behaves exactly the same from my testing.