# Jekyll Kramdown code in ordered list - number reset

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have the following code which resets the numbered list after adding a *liquid* code block:

```
...
6. Install the Ruby Google API client with `gem install google-api-client`, or if you prefer in a Gemfile:
    {% highlight ruby lineanchors %}
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9.1'
    {% endhighlight %}
(If you've never used [Bundler](http://bundler.io) before, you should start!)

7. Let's get a quick script set up to post a Google Calendar event to...
```

The problem is that the following renders as:

---

[image: fail]

---

The ordered list is reset, which is obviously a problem. I've looked at [many posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown) that [detail the markdown ordered list reset problem](https://gist.github.com/clintel/1155906) but none of them discuss *liquid* tags. I found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995467/how-can-i-put-a-liquid-tag-highlight-in-an-ordered-list) discussing the issue to no avail.

Here is the HTML output just in case it is necessary. The `<ol>` tag is clearly being broken by a `<div>` element produced by the liquid tag engine... and I don't know how to embed the `pre` block in the `<ol>` block...

```
<ol>
  ...
  <li>Install the Ruby Google API client with <code>gem install google-api-client</code>, or if you prefer in a Gemfile:</li>
</ol>
<div class="highlight"><pre><code class="language-ruby" data-lang="ruby"><a name="True-1"></a><span class="n">source</span> <span class="s1">'https://rubygems.org'</span>
<a name="True-2"></a><span class="n">gem</span> <span class="s1">'google-api-client'</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="s1">'~&gt; 0.9.1'</span></code></pre></div>
<p>(If you’ve never used <a href="http://bundler.io">Bundler</a> before, you should start!)</p>
<ol>
  <li>Let’s get a quick script set up to post a Google Calendar event to</li>
  <li>Let’s get a quick script set up to post a Google Calendar event to</li>
</ol>
```

I want to be able to put a *liquid* tag in an ordered list without it breaking the `<ol>` HTML element and resetting the numbering. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're out of luck. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/588

Comment: Some imperfect workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995467/how-can-i-put-a-liquid-tag-highlight-in-an-ordered-list

Comment: Do you leave a space before and after the number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those with this issue, adding extra info in front of the next number helped me.

```
6. Install the Ruby Google API client with `gem install google-api-client`, or if you prefer in a Gemfile:
    {% highlight ruby lineanchors %}
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9.1'
    {% endhighlight %}
(If you've never used [Bundler](http://bundler.io) before, you should start!)

{:start="7"}
7. Let's get a quick
```

Comment: This solution worked! It's kind of annoying to have to do, but it gets the job done. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The problem with this is that "(If you've never..." is not indented.

Comment: That problem can be fixed like this: `{:style="list-style-type: none;"} 100. (If you've...`

Answer (score 0):

```
6. Install the Ruby Google API client with `gem install google-api-client`, or if you prefer in a Gemfile:
    {% highlight ruby lineanchors %}
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.9.1'
    {% endhighlight %}

    (If you've never used [Bundler](http://bundler.io) before, you should start!)

7. Let's get a quick
```

As @Joshua Meyers Suggests in the comments, the problem is in the last line.
If you indent the line "(If you've never used [Bundler](http://bundler.io) before, you should start!)" the list numbers will continue.